# Fully fit images with different dimensions into the same sized div

Tags: html, css, image

this is a weird one because there are a lot of aspects out of my control. I'm working with a custom image carousel where the image is a background image and the containing div has a set width and height (these can't be changed) but things like background-position and background-size I can manipulate.

The problem comes from images of varying aspect ratios. If I just try manipulating the width and height, the image gets cropped. Trying something like:

```
background-size: 100%
```

will work with images that are wider, while:

```
background-size: auto 100%
```

works better for taller images.

```
background-size: cover
```

crops both sizes and in a perfect world I'd like to find a CSS only solution. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make images of both aspect ratios completely fit into the same sized div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`contain` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Values):

> contain
>
> This keyword specifies that the background image should be
>   scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

```css
body > div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.tall {
  background: #F00 url(http://www.placehold.it/500X1000) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.wide {
  background: #F90 url(http://www.placehold.it/1000X500) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<h2>I contain a tall image!</h2>
<div class="tall"></div>

<h2>I contain a wide image!</h2>
<div class="wide"></div>
```